# Efficient Index data structure to access tree nodes

Tags: swift, data-structures, tree

Working on an app with a tree data structure where each node can have any number of children. Each node of the tree has a type and a series of properties which include a label and a value. I would like to be able to synchronize nodes of the same type to have the same properties in the same order (by label) but not necessarily with the same values. I am looking for a Data Structure to be able to do this efficiently, ie without traversing the entire tree each time. Seems like some sort of index is the solution but having trouble coming up with a data structure that is not ugly to maintain. All the nodes and properties are classes and Identifiable and Hashable. What is the accepted practice way to do this efficiently? Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are nodes of the same type adjacent to one another in the tree? i.e., will it be possible to leverage locality in the tree for this access? If so, you may be able to avoid an external data structure for this. (And if not, and these properties could be distributed randomly across your tree, you'll likely need `O(n)` additional storage to perform that access)

Comment: They are not necessarily next to each other. Because everything is a reference type, I though of storing a dictionary of node references keyed by type, but want to make sure I’m being smart about it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Yeah, without getting too fancy, and without rearranging how your tree is organized, the likely simplest solution will be to store a dictionary keyed by type (storing `Set`s of nodes with that type, for `O(1)` insertion and lookup). With that in place, you can probably benchmark to see whether the solution is performant enough (time- and storage-wise).

Comment: Thanks Itai, that is actually the approach I am working with at the moment. I’m new to more complex data management so it’s nice to confirm that I’m not wildly off base.